# How to morph multi-part css properties with Mootools Fx?

Tags: css, mootools

There are some css properties that can only(as far as I know) be modified as a set of values, like *text-shadow* (`text-shadow:<xOffset> <yOffset> <radius> <color>;`). I've seen some referred to as shorthand values, even though I've never seen the longer syntax version.

So, in a nutshell I'd like to modify individual parts of a declaration like in the example code below in an Fx.Morph transition without resorting to transition-specific hacks:

```
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```

Let's say I need to fade the shadow out. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.Styles.textShadow = "rgb(@, @, @) @px @px @px";`

then just use like `this.tween('text-shadow', '#000 10px 10px 30px');` - but you need to define a base shadow first VIA MOOTOOLS. this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/6UADQ/10/

```
Element.Styles.textShadow = "@px @px @px rgb(@, @, @)";

document.id("moo").set("tween", {
    duration: 600,
    link: "cancel"
}).setStyle("text-shadow", "5px 5px 5px #000").addEvents({
    mouseenter: function() {
        this.store("shadow", this.getStyle("text-shadow"));
        this.tween('text-shadow', '10px 10px 30px rgb(0,0,0) ');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       this.tween('text-shadow', this.retrieve("shadow"));
    }
});
```

Comment: From a quick search in the core source I can guess rgba is not yet supported. Am I correct?

Comment: i can't say that i have tried but it would seem this way - i guess you can use morph on opacity in conjunction for the time being. i would ask this on the official mailing list - if it's an easy win, it may make 1.3.1, else, 2.0

Comment: According to the internets rgba should be supported in 2.0. Btw I stumbled upon some interesting features in mootools thanks to you. So I thank you once more :)